# 画像に沿って影をつけたい

Tags: android, java, android-studio, kotlin

透明部分があるpngに沿って影をつけたいのですがどうすればできますか？

調べても、ボタンやviewに影をつけるというは出てくるのですが、透明部分がある画像に沿って影をつけるといったことが出てこないので、わかる方がいらっしゃたら教えてください。（ライブラリーとか、コードとか）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく、この辺の記事の情報でしょうか。

[Material design / Shadow をより Shadow に](https://qiita.com/sho5nn/items/38ec4adba519c2977e2a)
　[Shadow の描画方法](https://qiita.com/sho5nn/items/38ec4adba519c2977e2a#shadow-%E3%81%AE%E6%8F%8F%E7%94%BB%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95)

> API level:21 で追加された android.view.View#setElevation(float) を使えば簡単に実現可能です。

方法は違うようですが、同じ記事中のここ [ZDepthShadowLayout](https://qiita.com/sho5nn/items/38ec4adba519c2977e2a#zdepthshadowlayout) で丸に影が付いています。

他にはこんな記事もあります。
[丸い画像に影を表示する](http://labs.septeni.co.jp/entry/2016/11/08/175940)
[Elevationで影が思ったように出ないとき - Speaker Deck](https://speakerdeck.com/ninjinkun/elevationdeying-gasi-tutayounichu-naitoki)
上記の最後

> まとめ
>
> - elevationはViewの高度を表す概念
> - 影が思ったように出ない場合は以下を確認
>
>   - マージン
>   - 背景色のアルファ値
>   - View階層
>   - NAVIGATION_MODE_TABSやめよう

---

HTML/CSS だと、filter: drop-shadow() になるでしょう。
[drop-shadow() - CSS:カスケーディングスタイルシート|MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow)

[CSSの「box-shadow」と「filter:drop-shadow」の違いを覚えたらちょっとテンション上がった](https://kuzlog.com/2017/03/09/1255/)
[box-shadowはもう古い？CSS新時代の「影の落とし方」](https://ferret-plus.com/8961)
[【CSS】png画像に影（box-shadow）をつける方法](https://norilog.net/css_boxshadow/)
　[2つの解決方法](https://norilog.net/css_boxshadow/#2)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
わかりにくくて済みません。自分がやりたいのは、
https://gyazo.com/edb3127261cc44e9b6ff901644973134
こういった画像の真ん中の針のとこも読み取って、そこにも影をつけることです。elevationを使うと塗りつぶし状態じゃないとうまく動作してくれないです。ZDepthShadowLayout のほうは、どうやって使えるようにすればいいのかわからず＆これも同じような理由でできなさそうだと感じたので試してないです。

Comment: 最初の紹介記事の途中にあるLevel20以前用の「9-patch 画像や、 hoge.xml を drawable フォルダにぶち込むなど、従来の方法であれば実現可能です。」という方法が当てはまるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: えっと、影付きの画像を用意して、それ使うということでよろしかったですか？
それも考えましたが、プログラムでできることはプログラムでやりたいので、先人でわかる人がいないかと思って質問させてもらっています。

Comment: そうすると、これ [How I extended ImageView to include elevation shadow.](https://medium.com/@qhutch/how-i-extended-imageview-to-include-elevation-shadow-2a41151a4156) なんかどうでしょう？

Comment: 返信遅くなりました。
思い通りのものができました！ありがとうございます。